# Status bar not showing in Firefox 19 using Status-4-Evar extension

Tags: firefox-extensions

I have used the Status-4-Evar extension before and it always showed the status bar. However the status bar is not showing in a brand new Windows7/Firefox 19 installation.

Any ideas or other similar extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status bar in the Status-4-Evar is basically just a modification to Firefox's Add-on Bar.  If that is disabled (by default, IIRC) then you get no status bar.  You can enable this under the `View => Toolbars` menu or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, from what I tested, that Firefox 19 breaks everything related to Status-4-Ever and add-ons that were embedded into the status/add-on bar. Uninstalling Status-4-Ever won't help though, as the add-on bar keeps being empty: I have Forecastfox+Nicofox and both disappeared when upgrading to 19, being on Windows and Linux (also, Foxtab also disappeard whereas being into the navigation bar instead). I also tried customizing toolbars and no, buttons for Nicofox and Forecastfox weren't available (and Status-4-Evar didn't show either). And oh, mystery, when downgrading Firefox, everything comes back again.

If someone has a better idea of what's happening, that would be nice, as I didn't see any feedback yet on the net about that issue, as of March 7th 2013.

---

EDIT: I sorted it out! I recreated my Firefox profile from scratch by reinstalling all my extensions, one by one, and reimporting most of my settings one by one: places.sqlite, my bookmarks, my passwords, prefs.js, user.js, etc, but did not include localstore.rdf. I fianlly managed to make Status-4-Evar work and behave like before, by doing this way. I think that position of elements in the status bar get corrupted or messed up when upgrading to Firefox 19 with an existing profile.